# The namespace name 'Expander' does not exist in 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls' on WinUI

Tags: c#, xaml, namespaces, winui-3

I develop winui3 desktop app in project reunion 0.8.2 and want to add expander to UI.

I see the Expander Class which should be referenced Namespace:
Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls
[Expander](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.expander?view=winui-2.6).

And install Microsoft.UI.Xaml (version 2.6.1) on nuget.

Check the example XamlControlsGallery which adds reference xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" and muxc:Expander in xaml.

I also follow up copying them to my xaml, but it displays

CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Expander' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

XLS0414 The type 'muxc:Expander' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

Do I miss something else? Here is my xaml
`

```
<Window
    x:Class="Expander.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Expander"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click">Click Me</Button>

        <muxc:Expander x:Name="Expander2">
            <muxc:Expander.Header>
                <ToggleButton Content ="This is a ToggleButton in the header"/>
            </muxc:Expander.Header>
            <muxc:Expander.Content>
                <Grid>
                    <Button Margin="15" Content="This is a Button in the content"/>
                </Grid>
            </muxc:Expander.Content>
        </muxc:Expander>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

`

Thank you for help.

Comment: Did you install the Windows UI Library from Nuget per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/expander)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I check it in link. This UI library API requires Expander class, Header and Content property. Except Content property can't find. Others are using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls. I also check XamlControlsGallery project again which is installed Microsoft.UI.Xaml. Others of nuget are about UWP.